# Expandable listview asynchrone task null pointer exception

Tags: android, asynchronous, expandablelistview

good morning
i tried to parse xml file and show the result in expandable list view so i used a method called prepareListData() to do the job and i called it in asynchrone task but every time i get null pointer exception.

this the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mofakra);
        zone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.research);
        //maListViewPerso = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        maList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listexp);
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {


            protected void onPreExecute() {
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Mofakra.this, ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {
                try
                {


                try {
                    prepareListData();
                } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } //appel de la méthode en interne
                Thread.sleep(10000);


                }

                 catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss(); 
            }
        };
        task.execute((Void[])null); 
        addKeyListener();
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
            // setting list adapter
        maList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
..............
```

this is the trace log in the execution ;

```
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.albir/com.example.albir.Mofakra}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at com.example.albir.ExpandableListAdapter.getGroupCount(ExpandableListAdapter.java:71)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getCount(ExpandableListConnector.java:397)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:460)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at android.widget.ExpandableListView.setAdapter(ExpandableListView.java:470)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at com.example.albir.Mofakra.onCreate(Mofakra.java:99)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-23 19:59:30.252: E/AndroidRuntime(21463):    ... 11 more
```

i tested the method previously without  asynctask and it worked but it take some time that's why i decided to use progressdialog and execute this method in a separate thread.
i hope that you help me.

Comment: What's happening in getGroupCount()?  That's where the error is.

Comment: public int getGroupCount() {
  return this._listDataHeader.size();
 }

Comment: Have you initialized this._listDataHeader before the Async call?  when instantiating the listview if that variable is null it will try to call size() on it and get a nullPointerException

Comment: think you i initialized outside the method the app doesn't crash now but i get an empty expendable listview :(

Comment: the listview doesn't appear after the asyntask

Comment: think you for hour help